# Broadcast fcm notification throughout the app in flutter

Tags: flutter

The question is I want to receive FCM notification from different view because I have notification bell icon which is updated whenever the notification is received.I have Profile View, Landing View, Dashboard View and others. So I have badge in there which needs update. However, I cannot receive the broadcast either using Stream or Notifier. The only option I have is to add a bulky line to each of these pages. i.e

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });

    _newNotification = true;
    _showNotificationWithDefaultSound(message.toString());
  },
  onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
    print("onLaunch: $message");
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
    print("onResume: $message");
  },
);
```

And also I need to add couple of functions to get it working.So my question is how do you receive it with the minimum possible lines.As I have tried Stream broadcast which only works for single page and I cant listen it from another page.Anyone if they had this issue please share.**All in the internet I am getting this solution and which is not applicable for me .**

```
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     print("Creating a sample stream...");
     Stream<String> stream = new Stream.fromFuture(getData());
     print("Created the stream");
     stream.listen((data) {
     print("DataReceived: "+data);
   }, onDone: () {
     print("Task Done");
   }, onError: (error) {
     print("Some Error");
   });

   print("code controller is here");
 }
```

[From this link which is good example](https://medium.com/@ayushpguptaapg/using-streams-in-flutter-62fed41662e4)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: Not much but yes.